# Bulk insert or update in web2py

Tags: web2py

I know there are methods like `bulk_insert` and `insert_or_update` in web2py. The former inserts multiple records at one go while latter  handles duplicate primary/unique key insert conditions(ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE). I want to do a bulk insert while also ensuring duplicate key condition. Is there anything like `bulk_insert_or_update` in web2py? If not, how could I achieve it?

I have written following query which I want to use something like `bulk_insert_or_update`

```
db.mcexlinker.insert_or_update(
db(db.mcex.example.like(‘%’+db.mc.element+’%’)).select(db.mc.id,db.mcex.id)
)
```

### Update

My table definitions are as given below:

```
CREATE TABLE `mc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `element` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `locale` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `synind` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_mc_locale` (`locale`),
  KEY `fk_mc_synind` (`synind`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mc_synind` FOREIGN KEY (`synind`) REFERENCES `mc` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mc_locale` FOREIGN KEY (`locale`) REFERENCES `locale` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mcex` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `example` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ranking` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enteredby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verificationstatus` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-unverified,1-verified',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `example_UNIQUE` (`example`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6233 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mcexlinker` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mcid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exampleid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `linkstatus` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0-new,1-verified',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_mclinker_element` (`mcid`),
  KEY `fk_mcexlinker_example` (`exampleid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mcexlinker_element` FOREIGN KEY (`mcid`) REFERENCES `mc` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mcexlinker_example` FOREIGN KEY (`exampleid`) REFERENCES `mcex` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Tables mc and mcex are linked through mcexlinker table to have many-to-many relationship.
Table mc and mcex are going to be populated independently. At certain point a scheduled job will run and link new entries in these tables by checking examples(mcex table-example column) which look like elements(mc table-element column) and taking their ids and inserting them in mcexlinker table. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are on Google App Engine, there is no advantage to using `bulk_insert` over simply looping and doing individual inserts. So, you might as well just use `update_or_insert` in a loop or list comprehension.

Also, `‘%’+db.mc.element+’%’` will not work, as `dc.mc.element` is a `Field` object, not a string.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your updated question, you could use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25426873/440323), but if you don't want it to be database dependent, you could do some looping in Python as follows:

```
for example in db(db.mcex).select(db.mcex.id, db.mcex.example):
    matches = db(db.mc.element.contains(example.example)).select(db.mc.id)
    for match in matches:
        db.mcexlinker.update_or_insert(mcid=match.id, exampleid=example.id)
```

You can also do some testing to see if it is more efficient to do the matching in Python:

```
elements = db(db.mc).select(db.mc.id, db.mc.element)
for example in db(db.mcex).select(db.mcex.id, db.mcex.example):
    for element in elements:
        if example.example in element.element:
            db.mcexlinker.update_or_insert(mcid=element.id, exampleid=example.id)
```

Comment: So how do I check if element is like the given string?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is "the given string"? Is it a single string value? Do you have a list of strings? Do you want records that match *any* string in the db.mc.element field?

Comment: I want records that match any string in the db.mc.element field. Example - if the column 'example' in mcex is 'foo'. Then the join would match if column in mc is either: 'fooblah', 'somethingfooblah', or just 'foo'.

Comment: In that case, your code is doing things backward. Your code would generate a match if mc.element were "foo" and mcex.example were "fooblah" (i.e., "fooblah" is like "%foo%"). But you want the opposite. It may be easier to do this in Python. See updated answer above.

Comment: I have a third table which links these two tables where I insert id's of bot these tables to show relation between these records. The query given by you only gives ids of mcex table.

Comment: Please provide the models of all three tables and explain exactly what your desired result set should look like.

Comment: Please see my updated question where I have given my table definitions and requirement.

Comment: Did [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25426873/440323) get you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Melinastoreservice/default/test?data={'name':'emma','age':'23'},{'name':'emma','age':'23'}

@request.restful()
def test():
    response.view = 'generic.json'

    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = 86400
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'

    def GET(data):

        import ast

        sett = ast.literal_eval(data)

        save = db.test.bulk_insert(sett)

        return response.json(save)

    return locals()
```