# Web2py's 'contains' function for 'instr' function of mysql

Tags: web2py

I have this mysql query which works fine for me

```
select * from mc,mcex
where instr(mcex.example,mc.element)
```

I have written following code in web2py for this as given below:

```
 rows=db(db.mcex.example.contains(db.mc.element)).select()
```

Its not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the web2py DAL, the query (which generates the SQL `WHERE` clause) can simply be a string of SQL code, so you can do:

```
rows = db('instr(mcex.example, mc.element)').select(db.mcex.ALL, db.mc.ALL)
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need a conjunction of conditions for the query, you can do so by chaining `Set` object calls:

```
rows = db(query1)(query2)('instr(mcex.example, mc.element)').select(
    db.mcex.ALL, db.mc.ALL)
```

Comment: It works when used as the only condition but shows error when used in conjunction with other conditions of join using '&'. It says cannot used string with query.

Comment: `Set` objects are callable (and return new `Set` objects), so you can produce conjunctions by chaining calls. See edited answer.

Comment: It works but what if in future I decide to move to SQL server or Oracle?